# Using OAuth 2.0 for Google to fetch Data from a Spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a programm that reads Data from a Spreadsheet. I know that I have to use OAuth or an API key, however I am completely lost to how to implement such a system into my program. I have looked around and found quite a few examples and "tutorials", however I just didn´t get any of them.(I am relatively new to programming). 
So can someone explain me in the easiest way possible how I implement a system that allows me to authentificates my programm so that i can read data from a spreadsheet(only the auth part, the rest i think i figured out).
If that is relevant, the Spreadsheet can be made public and it is just one column of Data. And i am using Eclipse as my enviroment.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Steps indicated in this [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java).

Step 1: Turn on the Google Sheets API

a. Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.

b. On the Add credentials to your project page, click the Cancel button.

c. At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click the Save button.

d. Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.

e. Select the application type Other, enter the name "Google Sheets API Quickstart", and click the Create button.

f. Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.

g. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.

h. Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

When all is set and done this is the code that handles the authorization using the client_secret.json you've downloaded.

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }
```